# credentials for SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have oracle sql developer installed and I would like to play with some queries using some dummy connection.

Is there any dummy credentials are there ? so that I can connect to Oracle DB

Comment: SQL Developer is just a client. If you need a database, you need to install one (or get access to an existing one somewhere).

Comment: (1) you can download oracle express: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html (2) you can use SQL Fiddle to work online http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to install Oracle (for some reason) and just want to "play with SQL" try something like http://sqlfiddle.com/

Oracle also provides some VM's and there are even docker images with Ubunto+Oracle you can run.

For the VM: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

For docker should be one of their official containers.

Sérgio